# Can we use hibernate with spring web flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am new to reactive programming I have started using webflux, previously I work on spring boot there I have used hibernate as a ORM framework. My doubt is what is replace of hibernate in reactive stack , which framework I have to use to connect & implement  database logic.
I am using mongoDB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can also use Hibernate with Spring Data JPA also with Webflux but you need to be careful not to block the threads. You can find more in their docs. If there is a reactive database client available for your database then you can use https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=spring+data+r2dbc

Answer (score 11):

you have to use either `R2DBC` or `Hibernate reactive`.
if you migrating an old service from spring boot to webflux, I recommended you to use `Hibernate reactive`.

when you use R2DBC, you can't use hibernate mappings and annotations.

according to hibernate reactive [documentation](https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/1.0/reference/html_single/):

When using a stateless session, you should be aware of the following additional limitations:

- persistence operations never cascade to associated instances,
- changes to @ManyToMany associations and @ElementCollections cannot be
  made persistent, and
- operations performed via a stateless session bypass callbacks.

Answer (score 8):

Hibernate is based on JDBC. JDBC is blocking. Blocking APIs don't work well in reactive stacks. Also, Hibernate under the hood uses ThreadLocals which makes it even worse candidate for reactive applications.

For Webflux, as the alternative to Hibernate you should look into [Spring Data R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) which does the basic database result to Java object mapping, but keep in mind that it's not a full fledge ORM like Hibernate.

You may also want to give it a try to [Hibernate Reactive](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive). With this you can use the power of Hibernate mappings in a reactive non blocking way. One thing that will not work though (at least not yet) is declarative transaction management with `@Transactional`.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what database driver you are using.

If using the jdbc driver to talk to your database, then yes you can use hibernate. But important to note is that the JDBC spec is blocking so every call to the database will be blocking, and must be placed on its own scheduler (thread) and you will most likely not get the full performance benefits of a fully reactive application.

If you want a fully reactive application you must use a database driver that supports the R2DBC protocol. Hibernate does not support R2DBC so can not be used if you want a fully reactive application.

Hibernate is most commonly used with relation database such as mysql, postgres, oracle etc and not NoSql databases such as monogDB.

If you are using MongoDB then there is [full support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.reactive) for R2DBC and there is no need for hibernate.